# counter loop that executes tasks at different iteration

Tags: c, optimization, iteration, conditional-formatting

I am writing this in C and let's say I have a timer counter that gets value from an external device. For simplicity, I will use a for loop that counts up to 10.

Then I have an action() function, whose job is to execute tasks at a different time.

```
int action (int counter) 
{
   if (counter == 1) //1st sec, hardcoded
      // do task 1
   if (counter == 2) //2nd sec, hardcoded
      // do task 2
   if (counter == 3 + 4) //7th sec (4 sec delay added)
      // do task 3
    //and so on
   //how do I count the total seconds elapsed?
   return seconds_elapsed;
}

int main (void)
{
    for (int timer = 0; timer < 10; timer++)
         action(timer);
    return 0;
}
```

I don't like hard coding the timer counter in action() function. Imagine you are doing more than hundreds of tasks in 3600 seconds. In the above code style, you will have to manually keep track of the delays. I would like to use a variable or a data structure to keep track of delays and perhaps increment on the next iteration. What would be the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: Have you learned about pointers to functions yet? If so, build an array of structures with one element being an elapsed time and the other being a pointer to function to execute the action. You then iterate through the array to decide what needs to be done. It isn't clear if it is all periodic or a single stream of operations.  You might need code to keep track of the time — perhaps POSIX [`clock_gettime()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/clock_gettime.html) or [`timer_create()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/timer_create.html).

Answer (score 2):

Two option: roll you own, or use a library:

- Roll you own: Consider breaking each distinct action into a function, and using array with function points. The 'action' will then become a lookup.
- Use a library - if you are going to have hundreds of actions consider using a library like libevent, or other event processing library. See below for few pointers.

Sample code to roll you own:

```
typedef void (*action_func)(void) ;

void action_a(void) {
}

void action_b(void) {
}

truct {
   int id ;
   action_func f ;
} action_table[] = {
   { 1, action_a },
   { 2, action_b }
} ;

int action (int counter)
{
    int n_actions = sizeof(action_table)/sizeof(action_table[0]) ;
    for (int i=0 ; i <n_actions ; i++ ) {
       if ( counter == action_table[i].id ) {
          action_table[i].f() ;
          break ;
       } ;
    }
    return seconds_elapsed ;
}
```

Adding/changing an action requires update to the table. You can additinal attribute to the table to change states, etc.

**Update 1 - C based cron/event libraries**

Light Weight:

https://

- github.com/staticlibs/ccronexpr
- https://github.com/troglobit/libuev/blob/master/src/cron.c

General Purpose - Probably overkill

- https://github.com/libevent/libevent

Answer (score 1):

my take on such design.
split code into two kinds of functions to make code readable - one kind of function makes decision based on counter and second is just basic handler.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef int (*scheduler)(int);
typedef void (*worker)(void);

typedef struct event {
    scheduler is_it_time_to_run_task;
    worker task_handle;
} event_t;


int every_five_seconds(int ticks){
    return (ticks % 5) == 0;
}

int every_hour(int ticks){
    return (ticks % 3600) == 0;
}

void sound_the_bell(){
    printf("bell\n");
}

void do_some_check(){
    printf("check\n");
}

int z=0;
int get_counter_from_device(){
    return ++z;
}

int main(){

    event_t events[]={
        {every_hour, sound_the_bell},
        {every_five_seconds, do_some_check},
        {NULL, NULL}
    };

    while(1){ //read some value from device
        int counter = get_counter_from_device();
        printf("counter: %d\n", counter);
        for(event_t *event=events;event->is_it_time_to_run_task;event++){
            if(event->is_it_time_to_run_task(counter)){
                event->task_handle();
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```